# How to debug apisix java runner's functions on Windows?

Tags: java, apache-apisix

As mentioned in the title, how can I debug apisix java runner's filters on Window ?

I tried to run it but it said :" java runner is only support epoll or kqueue "
Is there anyway to run the application on Windows ?
I'm using APISIX version 3.3.0 and APISIX Java Plugin Runner ver 0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing java plugin for APISIX on Windows. The only way I found was to use WSL2 Ubuntu distribution. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/wsl/install

If you also use docker be sure that your WSL2 enable integration for your image (in Docker Desktop: Resources/WSL Integration). I don't know why but I need to launch my container after I launch debugger and need to re-create it each time. So no perfect solution but a usable workaround